# How to get multiple return values from function in Lua C API?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I would like to know how to get multiple return values from function in Lua C API.

Lua Code:

```
function test(a, b)
  return a, b -- I would like to get these values in C++
end
```

C++ Code: (part where it calls the function)

```
/* push functions and arguments */
lua_getglobal(L, "test");  /* function to be called */
lua_pushnumber(L, 3);   /* push 1st argument */
lua_pushnumber(L, 4);   /* push 2nd argument */

/* call the function in Lua (2 arguments, 2 return) */
if (lua_pcall(L, 2, 2, 0) != 0)
{
    printf(L, "error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    return;
}
int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
int ret2 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
printf(L, "returned: %d %d\n", ret1, ret2);
```

The result I get:

> returned: 4 4

The result I expect:

> returned: 3 4

Comment: `int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);` should be `int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -2);`

Comment: lua_tonumber does not pop the value from the stack ... I'vent't check but I'm pretty sure. So perhaps lua_tonumber(L,-2) and lua_tonumber(L,-1) should do the trick

Comment: Note: Beyond the question, on the stack, you've got whatever results the function gave you for that particular call. You have to use the [number of results](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00895.html) to clean up the stack as needed, regardless of knowing what to do with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`lua_tonumber`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tonumber) does not alter the `lua_State`'s stack. You need to read it at two different index<sup>1</sup>:

```
int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -2);
int ret2 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
printf(L, "returned: %d %d\n", ret1, ret2);
```

Before you call `test`, your stack looks like this:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "test");  /* function to be called */
lua_pushnumber(L, 3);   /* push 1st argument */
lua_pushnumber(L, 4);   /* push 2nd argument */

|     4     |  <--- 2
+-----------+
|     3     |  <--- 1
+-----------+
|    test   |  <--- 0
+===========+
```

After its call<sup>2</sup>:

```
lua_pcall(L, 2, 2, 0) 

+-----------+
|     3     |  <--- -1
+-----------+
|     4     |  <--- -2
+===========+
```

An alternative would be to manually pop the results after you've read it:

```
int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
int ret2 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
printf(L, "returned: %d %d\n", ret1, ret2);
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> "*If a function returns multiple results, the first result is pushed first; so, if there are `n` results, the first one will be at index `-n` and the last at index `-1`*." [Programming in Lua : 25.2](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.2.html)

<sup>2)</sup> "*Before pushing the results, `lua_pcall` removes from the stack the function and its arguments*." [Programming in Lua : 25.2](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.2.html)

Answer (score 4):

You are taking the same index twice:

```
int ret1 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
int ret2 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
```

Stack is filled like this:

```
-- Lua
return a, b

+---+
| b | <-- top ("relative" index -1)
+---+
| a | <-- -2
+---+
```

So your C++ code should be:

```
// I don't know what ret1 or ret2 suppose to be.
// 1 = first on stack, or first return value?
// renamed to a and b for consistency with lua return a,b
int b = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
int a = lua_tonumber(L, -2);
// lua_pop(L, 2); // don't forget to pop the values
```

From [24.2.3 – Other Stack Operations](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html) :

> [...]The lua_gettop function returns the number of elements in the stack, which is also the index of the top element. **Notice that a negative index -x is equivalent to the positive index gettop - x + 1.** [...]

This negative indeces positioning is valid for all Lua functions regarding the stack access, including lua_tonumber.